# TableviewCell Auto layout with two equal width labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am new to Auto layouts, i am trying to design my view with Tableview with Tableview Cell and two Labels. But i am not reach with design similar in iPhone and iPad.

Can any one help to me Please.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 NSDictionary *views = @{@"label1":self.label1, @"label2":self.label2};
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[label1][label2(==label1)]|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
```

The key is `[label1][label2(==label1)]`.

Comment: I am using .xib not programatically

Answer (score 0):

Please add proper constraints to your views. like following

- Add pin width and height equal
- Leading space for 1st view
- Trailing space for 2nd view.
- Top/bottom space for both view.
- Horizontal/Vertical Spacing